# Why did Russ Buffalino tell Frank Sheeran to give him his glasses?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-irishman

In *The Irishman*, when Russell Buffalino (Joe Pesci) sends Frank Sheeran (Robert De Niro) to kill Jimmy Hoffa (Al Pacino), he first tells Sheeran to hand him his sunglasses. And when he returns after killing Hoffa, Buffalino hands Sheeran back his sunglasses. This seems to have a reason story-wise. Why did Buffalino do this?

Answer (score 2):

Sunglasses prevent eye contact.

Eye contact maintains trust.

In the situation where Frank did not turn up alone at 2pm as he promised, and instead turned up 40 minutes later in the company of Jimmy's foster son Chuckie and some unknown, suspicious, self-confident fella (Sally) — all advising him of the sudden change of plan and asking him to get in the car — maintaining Jimmy's trust was paramount to get him killed nice and clean.

Jimmy was in fact quite wary and hesitating, but Frank convinced him to get in, pretending to still be his loyal bodyguard. This would probably not work if Frank had sunglasses on.